# jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:103 invalid zIndex tween value: undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having an issue trying to fix this. My slider breaks every time I return to that specific page. keeps throwing error: jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js:103 invalid zIndex tween value: undefined

I have updated all css and JS files for revolution slider but still get the same issue.

*** Just as a side note - I am running it in Angular CLI ***

Can someone please advise?

```js
x.test("string"==typeof a?a:(a.currentStyle?a.currentStyle.filter:a.style.filter)||"")?parseFloat(RegExp.$1)/100:1},W=function(a){_gsScope.console&&console.log
```

```html
<div id="rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" class="rev_slider_wrapper fullscreen-container" data-alias="home-01" data-source="gallery" style="background-color:transparent;padding:0px;">
    <!-- START REVOLUTION SLIDER fullscreen mode -->
    <div id="rev_slider_1_1" class="rev_slider fullscreenbanner" style="display:none;" data-version="5.4.5.1">
      <ul>  <!-- SLIDE  -->
        <li data-index="rs-1" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="default" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off"  data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300"  data-rotate="0"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Slide" data-param1="" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-param10="" data-description="">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <img src="assets/images/uploads/slider-home-01-slide-01-background.jpg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center bottom" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
          <!-- LAYERS -->

          <!-- LAYER NR. 1 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-1-layer-1"
               data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['-127','10','5','10']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','bottom']" data-voffset="['-28','0','133','10']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="image"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 5;"><img src="assets/images/uploads/slider-home-01-slide-01-object-01.png" alt="" data-ww="['905','605','471','286']" data-hh="['824','588','438','307']" width="930" height="876" data-no-retina> </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 2 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-1-layer-2"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['10','10','10','10']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-231','-231','-231','-231']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 6; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px; font-weight: 400; color: rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);font-family:Playfair Display;font-style:italic;letter-spacing:0.2em;">Good for nature, </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 3 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-1-layer-3"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['10','10','10','10']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','top']" data-voffset="['-157','-157','-157','166']"
               data-fontsize="['80','80','80','70']"
               data-fontweight="['700','700','700','400']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 7; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 80px; line-height: 80px; font-weight: 700; color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1.00);font-family:Playfair Display;">good for you </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 4 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-1-layer-4"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['9','9','9','10']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','top']" data-voffset="['-16','-16','-16','299']"
               data-width="['470','470','470','355']"
               data-height="['123','123','123','122']"
               data-whitespace="normal"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 8; min-width: 470px; max-width: 470px; max-width: 123px; max-width: 123px; white-space: normal; font-size: 15px; line-height: 26px; font-weight: 400; color: rgba(121, 117, 117, 1.00);font-family:Lato;">We don’t just bring organic produce to your door — we nurture it from seed, we harvest it by hand and we understand the responsibility entrusted to us as farmers. </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 5 -->
          <div class="tp-caption rev-btn "
               id="slide-1-layer-5"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['10','10','10','10']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['62','62','62','98']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="button"
               data-responsive_offset="on"
               data-responsive="off"
               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"},{"frame":"hover","speed":"0","ease":"Linear.easeNone","to":"o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;","style":"c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bg:rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);bw:1px 1px 1px 1px;"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[12,12,12,12]"
               data-paddingright="[35,35,35,35]"
               data-paddingbottom="[12,12,12,12]"
               data-paddingleft="[35,35,35,35]"

               style="z-index: 9; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);font-family:Lato;background-color:rgba(142, 179, 90, 0);border-color:rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-radius:30px 30px 30px 30px;outline:none;box-shadow:none;box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;">SHOP NOW </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 6 -->
          <div class="tp-caption insight-dots-style-2   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-1-layer-6"
               data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['138','138','138','138']"
               data-y="['bottom','bottom','bottom','bottom']" data-voffset="['22','22','22','22']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 10; white-space: nowrap;">01 </div>
        </li>
        <!-- SLIDE  -->
        <li data-index="rs-2" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="default" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off"  data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300"  data-rotate="0"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Slide" data-param1="" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-param10="" data-description="">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <img src="assets/images/uploads/slider-home-01-slide-01-background.jpg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center bottom" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
          <!-- LAYERS -->

          <!-- LAYER NR. 7 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-2-layer-2"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['45','45','45','16']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['-163','-163','-163','-223']"
               data-width="449"
               data-height="36"
               data-whitespace="normal"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 11; min-width: 449px; max-width: 449px; max-width: 36px; max-width: 36px; white-space: normal; font-size: 34px; line-height: 34px; font-weight: 400; color: rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);font-family:Playfair Display;font-style:italic;letter-spacing:0.2em;">Live Organic </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 8 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-2-layer-3"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['47','47','47','45']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','top']" data-voffset="['-67','-67','-67','173']"
               data-fontsize="['80','80','80','70']"
               data-fontweight="['700','700','700','400']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 12; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 80px; line-height: 80px; font-weight: 700; color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 1.00);font-family:Playfair Display;">Live healthy </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 9 -->
          <div class="tp-caption rev-btn "
               id="slide-2-layer-5"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['181','181','181','146']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['103','103','103','4']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="button"
               data-responsive_offset="on"
               data-responsive="off"
               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"},{"frame":"hover","speed":"0","ease":"Linear.easeNone","to":"o:1;rX:0;rY:0;rZ:0;z:0;","style":"c:rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.00);bg:rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);bw:1px 1px 1px 1px;"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[12,12,12,12]"
               data-paddingright="[35,35,35,35]"
               data-paddingbottom="[12,12,12,12]"
               data-paddingleft="[35,35,35,35]"

               style="z-index: 13; white-space: nowrap; font-size: 16px; line-height: 16px; font-weight: 700; color: rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);font-family:Lato;background-color:rgba(142, 179, 90, 0);border-color:rgba(142, 179, 90, 1.00);border-style:solid;border-width:1px;border-radius:30px 30px 30px 30px;outline:none;box-shadow:none;box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;cursor:pointer;">SHOP NOW </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 10 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-2-layer-4"
               data-x="['left','left','left','left']" data-hoffset="['7','7','7','60']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','top']" data-voffset="['15','15','15','281']"
               data-fontsize="['24','24','24','15']"
               data-lineheight="['24','24','24','26']"
               data-fontweight="['700','700','700','400']"
               data-color="['rgba(105, 105, 105, 1.00)','rgba(105, 105, 105, 1.00)','rgba(105, 105, 105, 1.00)','rgba(121, 117, 117, 1.00)']"
               data-width="['520','520','520','356']"
               data-height="['29','29','29','none']"
               data-whitespace="normal"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['center','center','center','center']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 14; min-width: 520px; max-width: 520px; max-width: 29px; max-width: 29px; white-space: normal; font-size: 24px; line-height: 24px; font-weight: 700; color: rgba(105, 105, 105, 1.00);font-family:Lato;text-transform:uppercase;letter-spacing:0.7em;">Trust the nature </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 11 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-2-layer-1"
               data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['-276','-155','-99','10']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','bottom']" data-voffset="['-3','13','266','10']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="image"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 15;"><img src="assets/images/uploads/slider-home-01-slide-02-object-01.png" alt="" data-ww="['995px','605','471','286']" data-hh="['859px','588','438','307']" width="995" height="859" data-no-retina> </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 12 -->
          <div class="tp-caption   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-2-layer-6"
               data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['577','353','294','288']"
               data-y="['middle','middle','middle','middle']" data-voffset="['18','46','262','199']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="image"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 16;"><img src="assets/images/uploads/slider-home-01-slide-02-object-02.png" alt="" data-ww="['140px','140px','140px','140px']" data-hh="['140px','140px','140px','140px']" width="140" height="140" data-no-retina> </div>

          <!-- LAYER NR. 13 -->
          <div class="tp-caption insight-dots-style-2   tp-resizeme"
               id="slide-2-layer-7"
               data-x="['right','right','right','right']" data-hoffset="['138','138','138','138']"
               data-y="['bottom','bottom','bottom','bottom']" data-voffset="['22','22','22','22']"
               data-width="none"
               data-height="none"
               data-whitespace="nowrap"

               data-type="text"
               data-responsive_offset="on"

               data-frames='[{"from":"opacity:0;","speed":300,"to":"o:1;","delay":500,"ease":"Power2.easeInOut"},{"delay":"wait","speed":300,"to":"opacity:0;","ease":"nothing"}]'
               data-textAlign="['left','left','left','left']"
               data-paddingtop="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingright="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingbottom="[0,0,0,0]"
               data-paddingleft="[0,0,0,0]"

               style="z-index: 17; white-space: nowrap;">02 </div>
        </li>
        <!-- SLIDE  -->
        <li data-index="rs-3" data-transition="fade" data-slotamount="default" data-hideafterloop="0" data-hideslideonmobile="off"  data-easein="default" data-easeout="default" data-masterspeed="300"  data-rotate="0"  data-saveperformance="off"  data-title="Slide" data-param1="" data-param2="" data-param3="" data-param4="" data-param5="" data-param6="" data-param7="" data-param8="" data-param9="" data-param10="" data-description="">
          <!-- MAIN IMAGE -->
          <img src="assets/images/uploads/slider-home-01-slide-03-bg.jpg"  alt=""  data-bgposition="center center" data-bgfit="cover" data-bgrepeat="no-repeat" class="rev-slidebg" data-no-retina>
```

Comment: Please edit *your question* with the code, and also include a summary of what you have already tried to resolve the issue.

Comment: @FluffyKitten - Added code

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with Slider rev. Needed to update to the latest versions for all plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Tested on **angular cli 1.5.0 (angular 5)** (universal)

When using `*ngIf="showSlider"` with the Revolution slider this error seems to come up.

Basically RS doesn't like something else removing it from the DOM, it has attachment issues... in this case angular removes it and jQuery/RS has a little cry.

The Fix:

- use RS's api to destroy it, THEN let angular do its thing.

many ways to do this, this is how i did it:

```
ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.hideTheSlider === true && this.slider) { 
        // queries the conditional and if the 
        // slider already exists on the dom

        // RS's kill switch
        this.slider.revkill();

        // set the ngIf conditional for the html rewrite
        this.sliderLive = false;
        setTimeout(() => this.sliderLive = true, 100);
    }
}

ngAfterViewInit() {

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platform)) { // due to server side rendering check if browser
         this.preloadImages();

         /* initialize the slider based on the Slider's ID attribute */
         setTimeout(() => this.slider = $(this.el.nativeElement).find('#rev_slider_1').show().revolution(this.getSliderOptions()), 10);

    }
}
```